# Problems creating custom angular directive using Raphael

Tags: angularjs, raphael, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a custom angular directive to create pie charts using Raphael. However, I seem to be having trouble getting the SVGs to appear correctly (it seems to be stacking on top of each other (position: absolute; top: 0). However, when I created the Raphael object for each directive, I used the div within the template but the SVG doesn't seem embedded within the div. I've tried "replace: true" but it doesn't seem to work either. Does anyone know how to solve this?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y89W8/1/)

```
app.directive('piechart', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            dset: '='
        },
        template: '<div></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var r = Raphael(element.children(0));
            r.piechart(100, 100, 100, [scope.dset.male, scope.dset.female]);            
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use

```
Raphael(element[0])
```

instead

```
Raphael(element.children(0))
```

and template option is not necessary

like this.

```
app.directive('piechart', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            dset: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var r = Raphael(element[0]);
            r.piechart(100, 100, 100, [scope.dset.male, scope.dset.female]);  
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Roger, it works, but I'm not fully sure why - is it because of the template option or because of the element[0]?

Comment: It's because of the element[0], raphaeljs create <svg> and append to 'element[0]'---it is <piechart/> so template option is not necessary and your code doesn't work because 'element.children(0)' not found so it isn't appended to <piechart/>

Comment: There is no any watch or observe, so the picture would be the same even if dataset has changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.directive('piechart', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        dset: '='
    },
    template: '<div id="chart"></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var r = Raphael("chart");
        r.piechart(100, 100, 100, [scope.dset.male, scope.dset.female]);            
    }
}});
```